# How do you parse PKCS1?

Tags: parsing, rsa

Suppose I have a RSA-1024 keypair that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXgIBAAKBgQDlQmZUbHRpl9e9d1LmfUdXiV7UV1FZr2cHtTT4RwHWi1oMCJnZ
YEQQDDr76Qpow83CBqyEi8Ia4Fkvpb6XVekhNcCEAB/ac7UTHYJiB5aSE/zixiA1
pHpumlYt9RmItgPxNIv9DRRCTh0sr8Yqxv/85B1Z7bgaE5k5EGQPEi6i1QIDAQAB
AoGBAMzhciGwariTAjJIGMXy33bTRPPutLy5jBHPVu8qRfI9xtNKPHOPHERbKbtG
oA7QLWlgHXy2iVkLdainLpSAKj3Z6wNXv8plzfk7SIvC4OSgsEpWYUPBKCDBNRvd
HLGDmhUiXVgE1g9zAvG27ny+PPKilCcgo3Y//mUVJculig9hAkEA/+40B10YnTlt
Mj2XNi0u3pbWLnBT5DPm0+i2g8goKuhWXTpNGv9HKhtT1fouUsPvvb/HjS+hEgUH
bV1mqE99cwJBAOVSV4NBQvwbWcnU5i7TV6mKXhvHr4bOaENgk4MdNgVo6miZkiS5
T7kreSKrRmzrPJp22JtNhYtm7FmUsapczJcCQQCRLFZ5AtbugF+viv5WLeUTQC54
IyGDJem+tJerQwN961LqCSMpuDpu6RdyHjremeRJFxsjvCu6o/2ljMCpooV/AkEA
v0+MdpGxYkUnCPw19AaYcXZfwGk8hAgab2tYZN+vu5+lPxIvG7gFTIN6EXQ10pQF
AQ/48MchjASXVLx545h7jQJASe8x52j31Zr9t4yT3xItU3qfHdgJcNKHH2ICCTDS
QQ1dNxjufvP22lUey2Y1v6As0nFnxb2wFbqaH0EOORUOCQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlQmZUbHRpl9e9d1LmfUdXiV7U
V1FZr2cHtTT4RwHWi1oMCJnZYEQQDDr76Qpow83CBqyEi8Ia4Fkvpb6XVekhNcCE
AB/ac7UTHYJiB5aSE/zixiA1pHpumlYt9RmItgPxNIv9DRRCTh0sr8Yqxv/85B1Z
7bgaE5k5EGQPEi6i1QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

What is the format??
How do I parse this to get the private key d and public exponent e and modulus n to use for RSA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for the first is documented in [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2). It is the DER-encoding of the RSAPrivateKey structure.

The format for the second is documented in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1). It is the DER-encoding of the SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure, though Java named their class that represents it [`X509EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html).

When the DER encoding is base64 encoded and wrapped in "BEGIN" and "END" lines the result is usually said to be PEM formatted, and is described in [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468).

How to parse it? Find a library to parse it, these formats are complex and there is a long history of bugs in such parsers.